# VS 2013 Setup Projects Works on one server and does not on another

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, windows-installer, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

We recently migrated from VS 2008 to VS 2013 including a set of setup projects. One of the setup projects is meant to install a web application. It has one custom action that is meant to check the connection to the database. The code of the custom action has not been touched during the migration and the .msi works perfectly when generated from VS 2008. When I built the .msi from VS 2013 it works perfectly well when installing on our local development server, and throw an error saying that it cannot connect to the db when rolling out in the clients environment.

I'd really appreciate if anyone can point me into direction of search here. I know that I'm passing a correct connection string, and .msi generated from VS 2008 can connect to that db from the same server.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio custom actions that are installed for Everyone will run with the local system account. Connecting to a SQL DB will often fail because the DB doesn't allow the system account to connect, or because the DB is on a network share and the system account has no network privileges.

So it could fail because of the security settings of the DB or because the DB is on a network, and it may be nothing to do with the server. It might also connect if the install runs with a Just me setting because the custom actions then will run with the installing user's credentials. There may also be issues with architecture because servers are 64-bit and the 32-bit subsystem is optional, and you didn't say whether you install was x64 or your custom action code.